# Not able to update JSON file data by react.js

Tags: javascript, php, json

I am trying to update the comments.json by using one of tutorial example of Comment app of React.js.

I have done very few changes in code :

```
handleCommentSubmit: function(comment){
var comments = this.state.data;
var newComments = comments.concat([comment]);
this.setState({data: newComments});
$.ajax({
      url: 'test.php',
      dataType: 'json',
      type: 'POST',
      data: comment,
      success: function(data) {
        this.setState({data: data});
      }.bind(this),
      error: function(xhr, status, err) {
        console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
      }.bind(this)
    });
  },
```

Code of Test.php as folllows:

```
<?php
   $json = $_POST['json'];
   echo $json;

   if (json_decode($json) != null) { /* sanity check */
     $file = fopen('comments.json','w+');
     fwrite($file, $json);
     fclose($file);
   } else {
     echo "error found"; 
   }
?>
```

Any help will be good for me, because I am very new to JavaScript.

Comment: data: "json="+comment

Comment: I have tried but it doesn't solve my problem. Basically i am trying to update .json file with the help of React.js Framwork and php.

Comment: in you php file are you getting value for $json...If you are getting value then please check whether you write permission is allowed on file

Comment: Problem is that i am not getting the value of @json .. One i debug my code it always get in part:   else {

     echo "error found"; 

   }

Comment: remove dataType:'json'

Comment: According to [link] http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html , I have to develop server app to handle post, get query. So, is it the only way to update/read .json file ?